# Scoring function using CheckBox bool value

Tags: c#, function

I'm still quite new to coding and I've met some problem when making a scoring system for my "spot the difference game" using trigger from bool state that has been changed.
I've declared a `public int` and using it as starting value, then what I expect is when Player press an Image Box that I've set to transparent it checked the CheckBox so when the CheckBox has been checked, it decrements the `int` value and so on.
But when the value of `int` has been depleted, it doesn't spawn the MessageBox that shows the player that he/she has finished the game.

I've already tried to make my own code, right below:

```
public partial class FTD_PG : Form
{
    public int Check = 5;

    private void check_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.check_1_stat.Checked = true;
        Check--;
    }

    private void check_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.check_3_stat.Checked = true;
        Check--;
    }

    private void check_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.check_2_stat.Checked = true;
        Check--;
    }

    private void check_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.check_4_stat.Checked = true;
        Check--;
    }

    private void check_5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.check_5_stat.Checked = true;
        Check--;
    }

    private void WinState()
    {
        if (Check == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Congrats you win the game!");
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect is just to fix the scoring system, that's it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The MessageBox is shown in the `WinState()` method, but you're never calling it.

Comment: any advice where i must put it?

Answer (score 0):

You never call WinState that's why it never shows the message box.
Add WinState(); after every time you decrement Check and it will work.

Or

replace Check--; with WinState(); and decrement & check in that method to make the code look better:

```
    private void WinState()
    {
        Check--;
        if (Check == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Congrats you win the game!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hehe ~ it works! Thank you very much I'll try to be more cautious about details next time XD

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) to associate each PictureBox with its respective CheckBox.  Additionally, I'd wire up all the Click() events of the PictureBoxes to the same handler in the Load() event of the Form.  You can search for the controls using the naming pattern you established.  As each control is clicked, remove it from the Dictionary.  When the Dictionary is empty, the game has been won:

```
public partial class FTD_PG : Form
{

    public FTD_PG()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Dictionary<PictureBox, CheckBox> differences = new Dictionary<PictureBox, CheckBox>();

    private void FTD_PG_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
        {
            PictureBox pb = this.Controls.Find("check_" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
            CheckBox cb = this.Controls.Find("check_" + i.ToString() + "_stat", true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
            if(pb != null && cb != null)
            {
                differences.Add(pb, cb);
                pb.Click += Pb_Click;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
        if (differences.ContainsKey(pb))
        {
            CheckBox cb = differences[pb];
            cb.Checked = true;
            differences.Remove(pb);
            if (differences.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congrats you win the game!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like a bit complex, since I never know about "Dictionary" function, but I'll try next time. Thank you for introducing a new type of function ^^

Comment: No problem.  Dictionaries are quite useful and are used in many different situations.  It's a good tool to have in your skill set.  Good luck!